# QuickBlox- Attempt to invoke virtual method addDialogMessageListener

Tags: android, quickblox

I'm trying to enable the group chat feature using QuickBlox. Whenever I try to open the chat, the app crashes and I get the exception as mentioned in the title. What can I do to fix this? 
Posting my code below:

```
private void initChatDialogs() {
    qbChatDialog = (QBChatDialog)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Dialogs");
    Log.e("ERROR",qbChatDialog.getDialogId());
    qbChatDialog.initForChat(QBChatService.getInstance());
    boolean log= QBChatService.getInstance().isLoggedIn();
    Log.d("Logged",String.valueOf(log));
    QBIncomingMessagesManager qbIncomingMessagesManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getIncomingMessagesManager();
    if(qbIncomingMessagesManager == null){
        Toast.makeText(ChatMessaeActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    qbIncomingMessagesManager.addDialogMessageListener(new QBChatDialogMessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void processMessage(String s, QBChatMessage qbChatMessage, Integer integer) {

        }

        @Override
        public void processError(String s, QBChatException e, QBChatMessage qbChatMessage, Integer integer) {

        }
    });


    if(qbChatDialog.getType() == QBDialogType.GROUP || qbChatDialog.getType() == QBDialogType.PUBLIC_GROUP){
        DiscussionHistory discussionHistory = new DiscussionHistory();
        discussionHistory.setMaxStanzas(0);
        qbChatDialog.join(discussionHistory, new QBEntityCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object o, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());

            }
        });

    }
    qbChatDialog.addMessageListener(this);
```

Comment: What is question here ?

Comment: @ADM Whenever I try to open a chat group, the app crashes and I get an error saying that I'm trying to invoke a virtual method addDialogMessageListener on a null object reference, which obviously means I'm going wrong with initializing the object. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Add the error logs in question .

Comment: Add `build.gradle` in question .